# How to run another windows form on button click in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, licensing, desktop-application, program-entry-point

I am working on windows form application where i need to upgrade the windows form application software solution based on the licence key provided by the user.Suppose he has upgraded his software from basic to higher version.In this case we want him to enter the upgraded licence key which will be verified from our Central server and the software will be upgraded.
For upgrading the software i need to change the main class program file..

Here is the code for program file..

```
namespace UpgradeECV
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

}

Now as soon as user eneters the correct verified upgraded licence key i want

```
 Application.Run(new Form1());
```

to change to

```
 Application.Run(new Form2());
```

How can this be possible ..
Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With utilizing a simple `bool` flag that indicates user is licensed or not, you can then `Run` either `Form1` or `Form2`, like this:

```
Form form = isLicensed ? new Form2() : new Form1();
Application.Run(form);
```

Comment: Will this solution be application after we install the application as setup cd

Comment: Of course, it's so simple, it's all inside your program.cs, even before opening any form you can open a Registration from and ask user to get his/her license, then store the license somewhere and set the isLicensed flag.

Answer (score 1):

In this case  instead of running the Form1() class you can run some other class where you will compare the version and the decide which Form you need to open.

Suppose version is XX then you can open you First form else your second. This way you can achieve this, but I don't see any possibility of changing the code run time.